Getting Undefined when trying to estimate gas with Etherjs
const escrow = new ethers.Contract(config[network.chainId].escrow.address, Escrow, provider)
const gasEstimate = await escrow.estimateGas.depositEarnest(home.id, true, {
        value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") // Example ether value
});

Escrow contract deployed on sepolia
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xe05e01f4f8a7b9b18bCb46C52835f739A13827f8#code
Error:
Home.js:74 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'depositEarnest')
Not able to understand why it's giving the error. Tested the functions on remix , working properly.

Since you're using ethers v6, so estimateGas should be called using the contract's function instead of contract itself, i.e., contract.contractFunction.estimateGas(contractFunctionArgs).
So, instead of escrow.estimateGas.depositEarnest, it should be escrow.depositEarnest.estimateGas.
You can also refer to the v5 to v6 migration doc for more details.
Just replace this line:
const gasEstimate = await escrow.estimateGas.depositEarnest(home.id, true, {
        value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") // Example ether value
});

with:
const gasEstimate = await escrow.depositEarnest.estimateGas(home.id, true, {
        value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") // Example ether value
});


getting "errors.ts:694 Uncaught (in promise) Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x60825d5f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", "to": "0xe05e01f4f8a7b9b18bCb46C52835f739A13827f8" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.2)" error after the change

Are you able to call the depositEarnest function with those arguments? You can check that by calling that function on Etherscan.

yes, the functions are working correctly I checked it both on etherscan and remix

Can you share the exact args that you're passing while interacting with the depositEarnest function on Etherscan?

args : 0.0002 , 8 , true . I'm only facing the issue while trying to call from frontend using etherjs

Are you using the same account (on frontend as well as on Remix or Etherscan) to sign the transaction while calling the function?

Yes, same account on etherscan and frontend. On remix it was local blockchain

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
